# Use a thumbnail as a placeholder for Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

From the UX point of view, it will be great to show the user a thumbnail first until the real image completes loading, then showing it to him, but [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) uses only a resource file as the place holder like:

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .into(imageView);
```

So, how can I use a thumbnail URL as the placeholder? , and if I should use Picasso twice, then how?

[An issue](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/383) is already opened on Picasso's github page with this request, but seems it won't be added to Picasso as per JakeWharton. So how could we do it with what's available in hand?

Comment: What about setting the ImageView's thumbnail manually. You do not use the placeholder option from Picasso. Then you have the thumbnail until it's loaded.

Comment: What do you mean by manually?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks to raveN here & the comments on the [original request](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/383) on github, finally I've got a working solution:

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(thumb) // thumbnail url goes here
       .into(imageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(url) // image url goes here
                        .placeholder(imageView.getDrawable())
                        .into(imageView);
            }
            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });
```

The trick here is to get the drawable from the imageView (which is the thumbnail) after the first call & pass it as a placeholder to the second call

-- **update** --

I've made a [blog post](http://abdelhady.net/2015/02/14/loading-images-super-fast-like-whatsapp-part-1/) describing the whole scenario

Comment: I am using the same but thumb image is not setting .  `Picasso.get().load(thumbImageUrl)                          .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_avatar)                            .into(mUserProfileImageView, new Callback() {@Override                             public void onSuccess() {Picasso.get().load(imageUrl)                                           .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_avatar)                                         .into(mUserProfileImageView);}@Override public void onError(Exception e) {                           }});` even thumbImageUrl is getting correct values

Comment: @xaif I was using an older version of Picasso & the code in the answer here was working fine with me, but I didn't try it with the latest version yet, so I'm not sure what could be wrong in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response , please let me know when you give a try on latest version. BTW , my problem with this did not solved yet

Answer (score 3):

You could write a simple helper which calls Picasso twice (as you mentioned).

I've not tested it, but it should go like

```
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(thumbnailUrl)
        .error(errorPlaceholderId)
        .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                                // TODO Call Picasso once again here
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {                             
                    }
            );
```

There are a couple of different ways to get your Picasso called twice. One method I could think of (again, not tested) is

```
public static void loadImageWithCallback(String url, Callback callback) {
    Picasso.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .error(errorPlaceholderId)
        .into(imageView, callback);
}

public static void loadImage(String url) {
    Picasso.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .error(errorPlaceholderId)
        .into(imageView);
}

loadImageWithCallback("http://example.com/mythumbnail.jpg", new Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        loadImage("http://example.com/myRealImage.jpg");    
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {                             
                }
}
```

Edit: All I know is that Picasso provides this callback mechanism. I'm using it in my app to hide a ProgressBar that is displayed until the image is loaded. I'll hide it in success or error callbacks - so you'll have the option to get notified when image loading is done. Then you can simply call it again. I hope the above approach works.

Comment: Shortly, It is not working. Unfortunately, it seems that Picasso clears the ImageView when it is binded to it, so when the `onSuccess()` is called & trying to bind the second call on it, it clears the loaded thumb!. I think we need to get the bitmap retrieved from the first call to pass it as a placeholder for the next .. but how? !!

Answer (score 1):

I originally used AbdelHady's solution but found that the larger image is only loaded after the thumbnail is done loading so I came up with this instead.

Assuming you have a utility class in your project;

```
public final class U {

public static void picassoCombo(final RequestCreator thumbnail,
                                final RequestCreator large,
                                final ImageView imageView) {
    Target target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(errorDrawable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            thumbnail.into(imageView);
        }
    };

    imageView.setTag(target); // To prevent target from being garbage collected
    large.into(target);
}
}
```

**Usage:**

```
U.picassoCombo(
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load("http://lorempixel.com/200/100/sports/1/")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image_placeholder),
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load("http://lorempixel.com/800/400/sports/1/")
                .error(R.drawable.ic_image_broken),
        imageView
);
```

In the above example the placeholder is set first, the thumbnail url is set next, and regardless of whether the thumbnail request is done, successful, or failed, the large image request is set once it is done. If the large image request failed, then the error drawable is set.

The only issue is that if you use [`setIndicatorsEnabled(true)`](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.html#setIndicatorsEnabled-boolean-) the debug indicators don't show for the large request. As far as I can tell this seems to be by design according to [this issue convo](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/26)