# Setting a default image for null source

Tags: java, android

I'm making a movie review app using the New York times movie review API, the API gives me a string "src" with the image url, but some reviews return null.

I would like to use a image asset or vector assest when the API returns null, but I don't know how.

MainActivity.java

```
package br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    private MovieArrayAdapter movieArrayAdapter;
    private ListView movieListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
        movieListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.movieListView);
        movieArrayAdapter = new MovieArrayAdapter(this, movieList);
        movieListView.setAdapter(movieArrayAdapter);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TextInputEditText search_bar;
                search_bar = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
                URL url = createURL(search_bar.getText().toString());
                if(url != null){
                    dismissKeyboard(search_bar);
                    GetMovieTask getLocalMovieTask = new GetMovieTask();
                    getLocalMovieTask.execute(url);
                }else {
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout), R.string.invalid_url,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void dismissKeyboard (View view){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
    }

    private URL createURL (String movie){
        String apiKey = getString (R.string.api_key);
        String baseUrl = getString(R.string.nyt_url);
        try{
            String urlString = baseUrl + "?api_key=" + apiKey + "&query=" + URLEncoder.encode (movie, "UTF-8");
            return new URL(urlString);
        }
        catch( Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private class GetMovieTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, JSONObject> {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) params[0].openConnection();
                int response = connection.getResponseCode();
                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder ();
                    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))){
                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                            builder.append(line);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e){
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout), R.string.read_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return new JSONObject(builder.toString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout), R.string.connect_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                if (connection != null){
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject movie) {
            convertJSONToArrayList (movie);
            movieArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            movieListView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
        }
    }

    private void convertJSONToArrayList (JSONObject forecast){
        movieList.clear();
        try{
            JSONArray results = forecast.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject movie = results.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject multimedia = movie.getJSONObject("multimedia");
                movieList.add(new Movie(movie.getString("display_title"),
                        movie.getString("publication_date"),
                        multimedia.getString("src")));

            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Movie.java

```
package br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Movie {
    public final String title;
    public final String publication_date;
    public final String iconURL;

    public Movie(String title,String publication_date, String iconName) {
        this.title = title;
        this.publication_date = publication_date;
        this.iconURL = iconName;
    }
}
```

MovieArrayAdapter.java

```
package br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MovieArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

    private static class ViewHolder{
        ImageView movieImage;
        TextView description;
        TextView publication_date;
    }

    private Map<String, Bitmap> bitmaps = new HashMap<>();
    public MovieArrayAdapter (Context context, List<Movie>
            forecast){
        super (context, -1, forecast);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Movie review = getItem (position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.complete_review, parent, false);
            viewHolder.movieImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.movieImage);
            viewHolder.description = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            viewHolder.publication_date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.publication_date);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        if (bitmaps.containsKey(review.iconURL)){
            viewHolder.movieImage.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(review.iconURL));
        }
        else{
            new LoadImageTask (viewHolder.movieImage).execute (review.iconURL);
        }

        Context context = getContext();
        viewHolder.description.setText(review.title);
        viewHolder.publication_date.setText(review.publication_date);
        return convertView;
    }

    private class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private ImageView imageView;
        public LoadImageTask (ImageView imageView){
            this.imageView = imageView;
        }
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try{
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                try(InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream ()){
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    bitmaps.put (params[0], bitmap);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:elevation="@dimen/toolbar_elevation" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fab_magin_top"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:elevation="@dimen/rested_button_elevation"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/view">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/search_bar"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="@string/hint_text"
            android:elevation="@dimen/rested_search_elevation"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/movieListView"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Error Message

```
07-31 18:10:46.464 585-1419/? W/audio_hw_primary: out_write() limiting sleep time 65759 to 46439
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value null at multimedia of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:578)
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err:     at br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity.convertJSONToArrayList(MainActivity.java:157)
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err:     at br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity.access$300(MainActivity.java:34)
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err:     at br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity$GetMovieTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:145)
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err:     at br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas.MainActivity$GetMovieTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:110)
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
07-31 18:10:46.784 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 18:10:46.824 3083-3083/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas D/android.widget.GridLayout: horizontal constraints: x2-x0>=1120, x1-x0>=80, x2-x0<=219 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x2-x0<=219. 
07-31 18:10:47.114 3083-3109/br.com.pedro.pedrodaumas D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 499K, 19% free 3670K/4488K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
```

Comment: You are re-inventing the wheel here... You should look into using Picasso or Glide libraries for loading URL addresses into an ImageView

Comment: My teacher used this method so I think it would be easier to use

Comment: Sure. You're going to learn one day, though, that libraries make development easier, and many large companies use them rather than rewrite the functionality they provide. You may also discover that teachers aren't always correct, but that really depends on the course material

Comment: I know that, but I think it would take me more time to learn how to use that libraries then working around it. I appreciate your help but even if I used a library I don't know how to use a default image for when it return's null

Comment: Take a look here. Tell me that's not easier than an AsyncTask.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299758/use-a-thumbnail-as-a-placeholder-for-picasso

Comment: Looks simple..I'll try it out and update this post later, I would like if you could help me if I end up having trouble with something ^^

Comment: Alternatively, if you can check your data for null values just put a simple if not null check before you attempt to load the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to cricket_007 I was able to solve my problem by adding

```
if(movie.isNull("multimedia")){
                    movieList.add(new Movie(movie.getString("display_title"),
                            movie.getString("publication_date"),
                            "image", movie.getString("summary_short")));
```

to my

> convertJSONToArrayList

and adding

```
   if(review.iconURL == "image"){
        viewHolder.movieImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_import_contacts_white_24dp);
    }
```

over

```
if (bitmaps.containsKey(review.iconURL)){
    viewHolder.movieImage.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(review.iconURL));
}
```

on MovieArrayAdapter